# CSS keyframes animation-name

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

Should we us only mymove or can we use other names in the animation property.
Ex:

```
animation: mymove 5s infinite;

@keyframes mymove{
.......
}
```

i am asking that can we *moveleft* in both animation and keyframes insted of using mymove

Comment: You can use any animation name as long as  you have the ```keyframes``` set for that animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any valid identifying string with a matching keyframe.

In terms of what is valid, MDN has [a page covering the specifics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/custom-ident), but they
key points are summarised nicely in this quote from the [animation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-name#values):

> A name identifying the animation. This identifier is composed of a combination of case-sensitive letters a to z, numbers 0 to 9, underscores (_), and/or dashes (-). The first non-dash character must be a letter. Also, two dashes are forbidden at the beginning of the identifier. Furthermore, the identifier can't be none, unset, initial, or inherit.